# Is it possible to interchange mixed derivative in the convection equation?

Tags: partial-derivative

Let the convection equation $\frac{\delta u}{\delta t} + c\frac{\delta u}{\delta x} = 0$. I want to show that $$\frac{\delta^2 u}{\delta t^2}-c\frac{\delta^2 u}{\delta x^2}=0$$

I think it would be possible to differentiate the original convection equation with respect to t and x. Then the following two equations can be obtained.
$$\frac{\delta^2 u}{\delta t^2}  + c\frac{\delta^2 u}{\delta t \delta x}=0$$
$$\frac{\delta^2 u}{\delta x \delta t} + c\frac{\delta^2 u}{\delta x^2}=0$$
If the two mixed derivatives can be interchanged, I can conclude $\frac{\delta^2 u}{\delta t^2}-c\frac{\delta^2 u}{\delta x^2}=0$ by subtracting above two equations, but I don't know if it is possible to interchange it.
Is it possible?

Comment: This is true if your solution is regular enough. And given that only a shift takes place you need regular initial datum

Comment: Could you elaborate more what's the meaning of "regular enough"?

Comment: For example if $u$ is not even twice differentiable, then there is no way to conclude the equation you want.

Comment: You need $u$ to be twice differentiable. What you are saying is essentially this: let $u=f(x-ct)$ be a solution to the transport equation with twice differentiable $f$. Then it  is a solution to the wave equation (classical solutions to the wave equation have the form $u=f(x-ct)+g(x+ct)$ with twice differentiable $f$ and $g$). Here you do not have a backwards moving wave, $g=0$ and the one moving forward is smooth enough.